# why my canvas loop doesn't look smooth (Android)

Tags: android, loops, bitmap, android-canvas

Is there a better way of moving a canvas 600x3840 pixels left in a loop?
this  is I've done so far

```
 imagetwo = Bitmap.createBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(), R.drawable.bckgr1));



    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawBitmap(imagetwo, x,y, null);

    if (x==0){ 
        x=x-3; y=0;} 
    else 
    { x=x-3; y=0;  }

    if (x<-700)
    { x=0-3; y=0;} 
    else 
    { x=x-3; y=0;  } 
    invalidate();

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes!  Use an Animator:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/Animator.html

and a TranslateAnimation:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/TranslateAnimation.html